# How can I move my arm to a specified point in space using moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, dynamixel-controller, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Recently I am learning about moveit package . And I am created a move-it config package. I want to move my robotic arm (real hardware) to specified point in space (inverse kinamatics calculation). How can I program it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82151/how-can-i-move-my-arm-to-a-specified-point-in-space-using-moveit./) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-18**:
Do you already have a low level ros node implementing FollowJointTrajectoryAction for your hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There do appear to be a handful of tutorials that might be able to help you on the MoveIt! wiki page. The high level API's at the bottom of this tutorial page should be able to help you out:

http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-09-23**:
Have you seen any  python API /Example for that

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-23**:
For using MoveIt's ROS API with Python you just need to understand how to use publisher/subscribers, services and actions in general (http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Tutorials) and fill in the required information (http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_msgs).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Geek,

You could call MoveIt's `compute_ik` service ([service description](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetPositionIK.html)) and then use the computed joint positions to generate motions commands for your robot.

PS: <s>MoveIt's mailing list is (currently) the better place to ask MoveIt-related questions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/moveit-users</s> As of April 2017 [answers.ros.org is the recommended QA site](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/moveit-users/G8-HgIDutpw/-pn9EK6_AwAJ).

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2013-10-01**:
While this would work, it would be more efficient to send the pose directly to the planner.

**Comment by [puru](https://answers.ros.org/users/28672/puru/) on 2016-11-30**:
@bit-pirate

Hi! Can you please tell me how to call the /compute_ik service? What arguments should I be passing? If it is being published by any of the topics, how do I pass it?

Thanks!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-12-03**:
@puru Please don't use `comment` section to ask a new question. It doesn't get as much attention as you need, let alone it's not what comment section is designed for.